# How to autoscale VM in Azure

Tags: windows, azure, virtual-machine, autoscaling, azure-resource-manager

I have a windows VM on which I want to implement autoscaling.

Currently Azure Scaleset does not accepts VM which is already creted.

Has anyone implemented Autoscaling on Azure VM like its there on AWS based on CPU metrics ?

Comment: you should create VM's images which are inactive and will be used for auto scale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Has anyone implemented Autoscaling on Azure VM like its there on AWS
>   based on CPU metrics ?

As Rudi said, we can use Azure virtual machine scale set to achieve this. VMSS is scale in or scale out, create another VM to scale out, remove a VM to scale in.

In Azure, we can use runbook to scale up or scale down. Use resize VM size to achieve this.

We can set this via Azure portal:
Metrics-->Add metric alert-->select runbook:

[image]

**Note**:

In this way, scale up or scale down will **reboot** your VM.

---

**Update:**

If you want to scale Azure VM **horizontally**. I think we can use Azure **VMSS**.
Use auto scale rules to achieve it.

More information about Azure VMSS, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-overview).

**Update2:**

We can use Powershell to **copy managed disk to Azure storage account**, we can use this powershell script:

```
##create $SAS
$sas = Grant-AzureRmDiskAccess -ResourceGroupName shui -DiskName test -DurationInSecond 3600 -Access Read 
$destContext = New-AzureStorageContext –StorageAccountName contosostorageav1 -StorageAccountKey 'YourStorageAccountKey' 
Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy -AbsoluteUri $sas.AccessSAS -DestContainer 'vhds' -DestContext $destContext -DestBlob 'MyDestinationBlobName.vhd'
```

**Update3:**

We can use this script:

```
$rgname = "myrg"
$vmssname = "myvmss"
$newversion = "4.0.20160229"
$instanceid = "1"

# get the VMSS model
$vmss = Get-AzureRmVmss -ResourceGroupName $rgname -VMScaleSetName $vmssname

# set the new version in the model data
$vmss.virtualMachineProfile.storageProfile.imageReference.version = $newversion

# update the virtual machine scale set model
Update-AzureRmVmss -ResourceGroupName $rgname -Name $vmssname -VirtualMachineScaleSet $vmss

# now start updating instances
Update-AzureRmVmssInstance -ResourceGroupName $rgname -VMScaleSetName $vmssname -InstanceId $instanceId
```

More information about it, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-upgrade-scale-set#powershell).

Comment: Does that work for you? please let me know if you need more help:)

Comment: The above is vertical scaling.
I want scale my Azure VM horizontally based on cpu metrics.
I was able to add my VMs vhd inside the scaleset but now how would I be able to make changes to the code ?
Are there any simpler way to scale the VM horizontally ?

Comment: @kevinpeter If so, I think we should use VMSS to achieve it. we can use VHD to create VMSS with a load balancer, and use auto scale rules to scale up or scale down. More information about VMss, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-overview).

Comment: I am unable to RDP on those VM which are running under Scale set. Can anyone plz help me with this ?

Comment: @kevinpeter could you show me your load balancer settings? NAT rules

Comment: @kevinpeter We can set NAT rules to RDP those VMs, also we can deploy a VM in the same Vnet, work as a jumpbox.

Comment: Its empty but when I tried to edit it tell
Full virtual machine scale set support for the portal is coming soon. Adding or editing references between load balancers and scale set virtual machines is currently disabled for load balancers that contain an existing association with a scale set.

Comment: @kevinpeter  maybe we should use PowerShell to create Azure VMSS, set NAT rules to map azure VMSS instances, For now, edit load balancer was not support. As a workaround, we can deploy a VM in the same Vnet, and use private to RDP VMSS instance, work as a jumpbox

Comment: I was able to login into the VMSS instance.
But do I have to login into all the instances and update the code inorder to make changes reflect from the load balancer

Comment: No,we can create a image ,then use this image to upgrade instance one by one, just like change the VHD of instance, we can do it by powershell,

Comment: @kevinpeter We can follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-upgrade-scale-set) to upgrades for vmss, we can use powershell do an update one virtual machine instance at a time.

Comment: I created VM from the vhd, made changes to it, then after generalizing it, I tried to create a vhd out of it but I'm getting error. Below is the error message.

Save-AzureRmVMImage : The Capture action is only supported on a Virtual Machine with blob based disks. Please use the 'Image' resource APIs to create an Image from a managed Virtual Machine.
ErrorMessage: The Capture action is only supported on a Virtual Machine with blob based disks. Please use the 'Image' resource APIs to create an Image from a managed Virtual Machine.

Comment: Can we create a VHD from a Managed disk windows VM ?

Comment: @kevinpeter VHD used for un-managed disk, if you want to use managed disk VM to create VHD, we can use powershell to copy managed disk to unmanaged disk, save as a VHD, I will update it to my answer, please check it, also if it helpful, please don't forget to accept it as an answer, thanks:)

Comment: How can I copy managed disk to unmanaged disk using powershell ?

Comment: @kevinpeter Please check my answer, I have update it:)

Comment: how can change the source vhd of the VMSS to the newly created VHD ?

Comment: @kevinpeter Please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-upgrade-scale-set#powershell), also I have updated my answer with that PowerShell script, please check it:)

Comment: ,getting the following error.
PS C:\Users\kevin> Update-AzureRmVmss -ResourceGroupName $rgname -Name $vmssname -VirtualMachineScaleSet $vmss
ErrorMessage: The Image type for a Virtual Machine Scale Set may not be changed.
StatusCode: 409
ReasonPhrase: Conflict
OperationID : 0e8da9f4-817a-4db5-9b74-ca52fa3a2709
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Update-AzureRmVmss],
Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.Common.ComputeCloudException,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.Automation.UpdateAzureRmVmss

Comment: @kevinpeter maybe we should use this script to specify the newURI, `$vmss.virtualMachineProfile.storageProfile.osDisk.image.uri= $newURI`, please refer to this official [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-upgrade-scale-set).

Comment: getting this error - 
PS C:\Users\kevin> $newURI = "https://kevin1disks730.blob.core.windows.net/peter/MyDestinationBlobName.vhd"
PS C:\Users\kevin> $vmss.virtualMachineProfile.storageProfile.osDisk.image.uri= $newURI
The property 'uri' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At line:1 char:1
+ $vmss.virtualMachineProfile.storageProfile.osDisk.image.uri= $newURI
+ 
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound

Comment: Is there a way we can discuss this privately ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only way you can "scale VMs" horizontally is by using VM Scale sets.  Although scale sets do not support already running machines, I would recommend that you take a snapshot of your running machine, and use that as the image for VM Scale sets, and start with 2 images, then implementing your metrics to scale to more instances.

Comment: I was able to generalize the vhd and then add it VMSS and my test website loaded properly.
But now I am unable to RDP on those VM which are running under Scale set.
Can anyone plz help me with this ?